# How to cancel a FileCopy operation?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, file-io, io, copy

How to cancel a "My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile" operation?

I mean for example if I start copying in a application a file of 20 GB with that method (or IO. method) and then if I exit/close my app, the copy operation stills in background so I can notice that the OS decides to don't stop the copying even if the APP closes...

Then... I can cancel a FileCopy operation when my APP closes? How?

Thankyou for read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, use a filestream. Then in the FormClosing event, just type `FileStreamName.Close`